# How do I virtualise my running HDD?

Tags: virtual-machine, microsoft-virtual-pc

How can I create a VPC copy of my current HDD installation?  I want an easily restorable 'play' area to try and solve an installation problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For MS Virtual PC you'll want the recently announced [Disk2vhd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

[Acronis True Image Home 2010](http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/trueimage/features.html) has a feature that can turn the backup image to and from a Virtual HD (.vhd) image.

---

You could use [VMWare converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/). It converts to VMWare Player or Server. It doesn't convert to VPC, but the VMWare Player and Server are free.

Comment: He was asking to use VPC instead of VMWare...

Comment: the poster wants to create a VirtualPC image, not one for VMWare

Answer (score 1):

If you want to play with your current windows installation, you don't need to use VPC. Use the free [VMware Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/) and use the [vCenter Converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/) to convert your physical partition to virtual.